# Is modifying the request object in express.js bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I joined a small team of devs for a start up.  We have not even launched yet.  I have been handed a backend service written in node/express.  I have not worked with this tech beyond small pet projects.  I was looking into implementing a style guide just to keep code consistent, with the goal of implementing this across other backend services as well.

That brought me to the Airbnb style guide.  This part jumped out at me.
[Never mutate parameters](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--mutate-params)

```js
// bad
function f1(obj) {
  obj.key = 1;
}

// good
function f2(obj) {
  const key = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'key') ? obj.key : 1;
}
```

In express there are typically controllers that get defined like so:

```js
async function someController(req, res, next) {

  // I've seen similar code to this
  req.someNewProp = "Some new value."

  res.status(200).json({"someJSONKey":"someJSONVal"});
}
```

Middleware typically gets defined like this:

```js
// Route
router.get('/endpoint', function1, function2)

async function function1(req, res, next) {

  // I've seen similar code to this
  req.someNewProp = "Some new value."

  // Pass req and res to function2
  next();
}
```

I notice that the `req` object, as it gets passed around gets modified a lot.  Data gets added to this object in middleware and other functions as it is passed along before the response is returned.  The original dev that authored the code referred to it as "keeping things in request scope."  But that seems to directly contradict a major point in the style guide and made me wonder if this is bad practice.

So the question now is, is there a "better" or more widely accepted way to keep track of things in the context of the request that is not mutating the original request object?  What are some approaches of doing this?

Comment: That recommendation is mainly applicable to objects that represent program state. If it's just a way to package the parameters to a function, it's not generally a problem.

Comment: `req` is the only place where you can store request-related staff by default. Of course, you can assign each request its own unique identifier (but you again need to store it in the `req`) and use it to store all request related info elsewhere. But going this way you will need to add expiration to those records. So all in all it's not so bad to modify `req`

Comment: Airbnb is a style guide, i.e an opinionated linter, I wouldn't touch it because it forces semicolons (additionally in its good/bad example for not using semicolons it uses an inline async IIFE, which is bad practice in itself) ewww, closing as opinion-based

Comment: @LawrenceCherone The style guide is the reason I went down the rabbit hole.  I'm more interested in if modifying the request directly is considered bad practice and what alternative approaches are.

Comment: There is no easy alternative in Express.  Middleware needs to pass on its results to request handlers that come later in the processing and the `req` object is THE way to do that.  Express is specifically designed this way and it EXPECTS you to add/modify properties on the `req` object.  This is central to its design.  I'd ignore that airbnb guide recommendation in this case.  Note that these are guides, not rules and that's for a reason - they don't universally apply in all circumstances.  This is one of those circumstances where they don't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the express docs I found this bit in the middleware section:

> Middleware functions can perform the following tasks:
>
> 1. Execute any code.
> 2. **Make changes to the request and the response objects.**
> 3. End the request-response cycle.
> 4. Call the next middleware function in the stack.

[Middleware Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

So it's probably safe to say that if the docs explicitly say that we can modify req and response objects in middleware, it is probably not bad practice.

Comment: You are missing the important info about res.locals. Modifying the req is sometimes a bad idea.

Comment: @user2495085 can you say more about in what cases res.locals is better than the req object and why?  It seems like res.locals is typically used when rendering views and not for passing data between middleware and other parts of the controller.

Comment: req.params is being overwritten in every middleware, so you cannot modify it. Check here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2911

Comment: I feel like you're still not answering the initial question.  See docs for route parameters @ https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

This is for URL parameters specifically, so it doesn't really make sense to modify these values in middleware or elsewhere.  I'm talking about adding keys to the request object at the object's root.

Comment: I had a case where I modifying the req.params would have been a comfortable solution, but as discussed, it is not possible. - That's my message.

Answer (score 3):

Express provides a name space for applications to store request/response processing variables by adding them as properties of [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.locals). This seems a better choice than attaching not standard properties to the request or response objects themselves.

In similar fashion, global application variables can be stored as properties of [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.locals)

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a `locals` property defined for `router` instances. I have placed a reference to global router instance options in `res.locals` as the first middleware step in a route I wrote, but that was my choice.

It can happen that request properties **do** need to be changed during processing, such as `req.path`, but this is not something to avoid at all costs. For example Express provides `req.originalURL` so you can  recalculate path components any time you need to *by deliberate design*.

You may find Express gets more interesting with use - I've only recently learned of and passed an `error` object argument to the `next` function. As for the Airbnb guide quote in the post: underwhelming  in a word! The "good" and "bad" code quoted in the post *don't do the same thing*.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bad practice, this is the idea behind the middleware in express, in the simple definition, middlewares are functions that can modify the request and response object or even decide if the flow of the request continue or it's terminated. However you have to be careful and don't set a value in a pre-existing property or you can have some strange behaviors, also if the information that you are going to store in the request in big, you can think in other strategies for instance store the information in a memory database as **Redis**.

Comment: You are missing the important info about res.locals. Modifying the req is sometimes a bad idea.